# Does semodule -i need to be run after every SELinux policy update?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, selinux, rhel6

On RHEL and CentOS servers, when the `selinux-policy-*` RPM packages receive an update, is it always necessary to manually reload any custom modules I have built? When I see an update to `selinux-policy-*`, I have always reloaded any modules manually.

```
semodule -i /root/selinux/*.pp
```

If they must always be reloaded manually, is there a preferred method to make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is very simple: no. Modules are replaced by name and the version number. Unless you name your module same as a module provided by the official SELinux policy (which would be really silly indeed), you should be safe. No need to reload.